# Can't set default directory in PyQt's QFileDialog.getSaveFileName

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm using the following PyQt code, which is about as bare-bones as I can make it:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Save file as", "/")
print "Filename:",filename
```

According to the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName), the (optional) third argument to `getSaveFileName` is supposed set the default directory and/or file the dialog is set to. But when I run it on my OS X machine (Yosemite, version 10.10.4), it always puts me in my `~/Documents` directory with no filename specified. I've tried a number of things, but no matter what I specify for that third argument (as well as trying the named argument `directory`), it always starts in `~/Documents`.

I'm using Python 2.7.6, Qt version 4.7.4, and PyQt version 4.8.5.

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting the sandboxing behavior?

Comment: Tested your sample code, on Windows (PyQt4, Windows 10, Python 2.7.10), and there is no issue there.  It first goes to the `C:` for `/` and any other folder I put in for the third item.  It looks like it is just a mac issue.

Comment: Thank you, ekhumoro. I'm running into this on version 10.10 Yosemite, but it looks to be the same issue.